# Listing items with specific alignment

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

How do I do list items so that the number is adjacent to the first item? For example:

```
1. a. Eggs
   b. Feathers

2  a. Mention two...

   b. How can we...

   c. List three...
```

With good spacing and also maybe if multiple choice question of choice large capital letters, like

```
1. What is the name given....
   A. Hen
   B. cock

   D. None of the above
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy with the package [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip]
\item
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\alph*.]
\item Eggs.
\item Feathers.
\end{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,itemsep=\baselineskip,label=\alph*.]
\item Mention two\dots
\item How can we\dots
\item List three\dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\item What is the name given\dots
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,label=\Alph*.]
\item Hen
\item Cock
\item[]\refstepcounter{enumii}
\item None of the above
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need any clarification.